# Why is the biconditional used to verify the equivalence of propositions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm starting my journey into math with a foundation in formal logic. I was wondering if the bi-conditional logical connective is used to verify the equivalence of propositions, as a matter of fact. I was studying some text where '$\iff$' was used to compare two compound propositions. It went something like:

I have $2$ propositions:
$p$ and $q$

Then I want to check the equivalence of two compound propositions:
$(p \implies q)$ and $(q \implies p)$

In the text, the compound propositions were compared using '$\iff$' like so:
$(p \implies q) \iff (q \implies p)$

Even though the truth tables were drawn out to show that the compound propositions were not equivalent, the author took an extra step and used the bi-conditional to compare them as well.

[image]

Why do this? Is it because the $\iff$ is true only when both propositions are equivalent (both true or both false)?  If so, doesn't that make the bi-conditional connective the way to go when verifying the equivalence of any two mathematical propositions? For example, if the bi-conditional's truth table contains 1's all the way, are the compound propositions equivalent?

Comment: Yes because we say that they are logical equiv when they have the same truth values and this means that $p \leftrightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for propositions $\varphi(P,Q), \psi(P,Q)$ we have $\varphi \longleftrightarrow \psi$ for every possible assignment of truth values to $P$ and $Q$, that is, $\varphi \longleftrightarrow \psi$ is a tautology, if and only if $\varphi \equiv \psi$.

Similarly for the material conditional, $\varphi \longrightarrow \psi \equiv \top$ if and only if $\varphi \vDash \psi$.